# How to add document to Firestore and return Observable<T>

Tags: angular, firebase, observable, angularfire

Adding a document to a Firestore collection using @angular/fire returns a Promise. What I want to do is add the document, but then return an Observable of the created document. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
colRef: AngularFirestoreCollection = this.afs.collection<Session>('sessions');   

add(session: Session): Observable<Session> {
         return this.colRef.add(session).then((docRef) {
           return this.colRef.doc<Session>(docRef.id).valueChanges();
         })    
      }
```

Of course this doesn't work, it's trying to return a `Promise<Observable<Session>>`. I know *why* it's not working, but not how to achieve what I'm after. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the RxJS [`from`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/from) method with [`switchMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap) operator. Try the following

```js
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

add(session: Session): Observable<Session> {
  return from(this.colRef.add(session)).pipe(
    switchMap((docRef) => this.colRef.doc<Session>(docRef.id).valueChanges());
  );
}
```

`from` could be used to convert a promise to an observable.